# java.io.FileNotFoundException during accessing mysql database in android app from local server

Tags: android, mysql, android-asynctask, localhost

I am trying to connect my android app to the MySQL database stored on local server using `WampServer`. But I m getting following error. Can anybody help to solve this error?

Here's my log file:

```
I/System.out: [socket][/192.168.43.1:56854] connected I/System.out:
[CDS]rx timeout:0 I/System.out: [CDS]SO_SND_TIMEOUT:0 I/System.out:
[OkHttp] sendRequest>> I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
http://192.168.43.147/login.php W/System.err:     at
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
W/System.err:     at com.example.dummy.dbconnect.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:59) 
W/System.err:     at com.example.dummy.dbconnect.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:23)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
W/System.err:     at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
W/System.err:     at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
D/WindowClient: Add to mViews:
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{585d13d V.E......
R.....I. 0,0-0,0}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@e98b1da
E/OpenGLRenderer: PerfServiceNative_notifyRenderTime init fail!
D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x7fa288b800 D/ViewRootImpl:
hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{6cc9663 Login
Status,ident = 2} D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x7fa288b800
initialize window=0x7fa8c69c10, title=Login Status D/Surface:
Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7fa8c69c00) D/Surface:
Surface::connect(this=0x7fa8c69c00,api=1) W/libEGL:
[ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1 D/IMGSRV:
gralloc_register_buffer:1373: hnd=0x7fa284efc0 ID=584250 fd=50 ref=1
I/ActivityThreadEui: schedulePauseActivity
com.example.dummy.dbconnect.MainActivity finished=false
userLeaving=false configChanges=0 dontReport=false D/ActivityThread:
ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{b5ed5c2
token=android.os.BinderProxy@31c7710
{com.example.dummy.dbconnect/com.example.dummy.dbconnect.MainActivity}}
D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 0 /
android.os.BinderProxy@31c7710 I/ActivityThreadEui:
scheduleStopActivity com.example.dummy.dbconnect.MainActivity
show=true configChanges=0 V/ActivityThread: Finishing stop of
ActivityRecord{b5ed5c2 token=android.os.BinderProxy@31c7710
{com.example.dummy.dbconnect/com.example.dummy.dbconnect.MainActivity}}:
show=true win=com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow@8e835bf
D/ActivityThread: ACT-STOP_ACTIVITY_SHOW handled : 0 /
android.os.BinderProxy@31c7710 I/ActivityThreadEui: handleSleeping
sleeping=true screenOn=false Application terminated.
```

Comment: Post code too where you are calling service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing wrong URL.
Check your local wamp server URL i.e path where you stored your login.php file as well as  URL you are calling from android application to access that file.